# Are class variables shared across scripts?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on a set of Python projects with a lot of shared back-end functionality. To avoid code duplication, I've put this shared functionality into modules.

One such module is an event system. I want the event system to be global across a single project, so I defined an `EventDispatcher` class with class-level variables and methods:

```
event_name = str
event_data = Any
listener_callback = Callable[[event_name, event_data], None]

class EventDispatcher:
    # event name, List<event_callback>
    _listeners: Dict[event_name, Set[listener_callback]] = {}

    @classmethod
    def register_listener(cls, event: event_name, listener: listener_callback) -> None:
        # get the existing list of listeners for this event and append the new listener to it
        listener_callbacks: Set[listener_callback] = cls._listeners.get(event, set())
        listener_callbacks.add(listener)

        # put the listener list back in the map
        cls._listeners[event] = listener_callbacks

    #other listener methods follow
```

Because everything is class-level, I should be able to call `EventDispatcher.register_listener` in any class in my project, and all of the registered listeners should be added to the same list.

My concern is the other projects. Because of the amount of shared functionality, I'm running all projects from the same virtual environment. Will this cause `EventDispatcher` and co. to be shared across all code in the virtual environment, so events registered in one project can be fired from another, or will each project get its own copy?

As a followup question, if the shared virtual environment *does* cause `EventDispatcher`'s class variable to be shared across every project in the virtual environment, will giving each project a separate virtual environment produce the behavior I actually want?

Comment: Created objects (like this) are only hold in the interpreter that executed the creation code. They are not shared between different running interpreter instances (if not special measures are taken like sharing memory).

Comment: you can't share between two running program. Every running program has own memory for variables. So if every project means different running program then they use separted varaibles.

Comment: To be more accurate: they are shared within one process. One application can spawn multiple processes. They will have different versions of the class attribute, but they can be copies from the parent process when a fork is done.

Comment: If the module containing the `EventDispatcher` class is `import`ed by other scripts by the current process' Python interpreter, then the values of any class-level attributes will be shared due to the way Python caches modules when they're first loaded. If other Python interpreter processes are started, they each will contain their own (separate) cached copy of the module.

Answer (score -1):

No. As long as your programs are in different files and you aren't importing a file containing the `EventDispatcher` class, it will not be shared in any way.

---

A virtual environment will only share python version and installed packages.

Comment: Programs will be in different files, but each program will import the `EventDispatcher` class. I just want to make sure each program imports a separate copy of `EventDispatcher` rather than sharing one with the other running programs.

Comment: @computerfreaker each instance will be separate.